# CSS - position div on top right corner of a table

Tags: html, css

Please find below screenshots. I would like to position export icon on top right side of a table. If I give `float:right`, the icon div positions next to the table.

Without float:right

[image: icon without float:right]

```
<div style="float: right;">
       <i class="ebIcon ebIcon_export ebIcon_interactive" title="Export"></i>
   </div>
```

[image: export icon]

Parent div of icon:

```
height: 100%;
padding: 16px 0;
```

And there is a table div below icon div:

```
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
```

As this will be a part of plugin, I have to make sure that export icon has always position on right side of a top of a table

**How do I position icon div on top right side of a table div ?**

Comment: What is the width of the parent div?

Comment: Can you share your entire code please :) ?

Comment: Is the div inside the table or not? Provide us with some html plz

Comment: @Gerard parent div width is not mandatory.

Comment: @AmirShahbabaie div is outside the table. Table has its own div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy all of your elements in this type of questions, however to give you a general sense whenever you have a display `block` component such as div, it takes the whole horizontal space that is available.

So to move an `i` or `span` which are `inline` elements you can just do `text-align: right`:

Here is an example:

```css
div {
  background: grey;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 1rem;
}
div span {
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>☺</span>
</div>
```

In order to demonstrate that the **div (`block` elements)** expands on horizontal space I gave it a gray background color.

And please stop using floats, [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a much better solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure div has the same width that the table.
 Add text-align:rigth to div

Answer (score 0):

you can use following class:

```
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}

<div style="float: right;">
  <i class="ebIcon ebIcon_export ebIcon_interactive" title="Export"></i>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```